# Difference between var++ and var+1

Tags: c, struct

I'm new to coding and I was doing an online activity where I had to use pointers to increase the age of a person through a different function. So in the function I was trying `age + 1` instead of `age++` (age is the part of a  struct) and it was showing incorrect. Could someone tell me why this is not correct? Here's the code that I wrote -

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  char * name;
  int age;
} person;

/* function declaration */
void birthday(person * p);

void birthday(person * p){
    p->age++; // This is the same.. 
    //(*p).age++; // ... as this would be
}

int main() {
  person john;
  john.name = "John";
  john.age = 27;

  printf("%s is %d years old.\n", john.name, john.age);
  birthday(&john);
  printf("Happy birthday! %s is now %d years old.\n", john.name, john.age);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `var++` increments `var`. `var + 1` does not. You should show the code that was not working.

Comment: age+1 just returns the value of age plus 1, but does not modify the variable. age++ or age+=1 modify the variable. It would help if you wrote more clearly what you mean with "it was showing incorrect". I assume you did not get the result that you expected. And please remove the tag `function-pointers`, this has nothing to do with it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `++` operator increments a variable, that is it computes an incremented value and assigns it back to the same variable, whilst the `+` operator just computes a sum of its operands (hence `+` can be applied to constants, like `3+7`, and `++` can not).

So when you try to replace `p->age ++;` with a single plus, you need also to explicitly do the assignment:

```
p->age = p->age + 1;
```

Be aware also that the increment operator `++` exists in two variants, as a pre-increment: `++ var`, and post-increment: `var ++`. They both increment the variable, but the former returns a value incremented while the latter returns the value before incrementation. Examples:

++ var:

```c
    int var, res;
 
    var = 5;
    res = ++ var;
    printf( "var: %d, res: %d\n", var, res);
```

outputs

```
var: 6, res: 6
```

var ++:

```c
    int var, res;
 
    var = 5;
    res = var ++;
    printf( "var: %d, res: %d\n", var, res);
```

outputs

```
var: 6, res: 5
```

https://ideone.com/7i86Dj

Same rules apply to a prefix and postfix decrement operator: `--var` and `var--`.

Answer (score -1):

I have checked in online [compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler)

And for me both the lines below are working.

```
p->age = p->age + 1;

p->age+=1;
```

Comment: In the latter example you used the `+=` operator while OP asks about `+` alone.